# Does SVN support copying a folder non-recursively?

Tags: svn

Can I specify the depth of an svn copy? (similar to the --depth argument of a checkout command) I would like to make a copy of all of the files immediately under a folder but not any of the sub-folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SVN does not copy a folder with it's content it can't be controlled. If you copy the folder only it's reference will be created.

The simplest solution would be to do a simple copy (checkout) and delete the not needed folders from there.

Comment: is it possible to copy recursively including the content of the subfolders ?

Comment: As it mentioned in the answer. No.

Comment: thanks for the reply... i have solved my problem by doing svn copy URL1 URL2....which actually create tag but doing what i wanted...thanks